# How to catch my application's crash report

Tags: android

I am developing android application. I want to send an email to myself whenever my app crashes on a device, so that I can find my application's crash report through email. How can I implement this concept in my app? Have any exception handler for it?

Answer (score 18):

I am catching un-handled exceptions by using this in my activity's `onCreate()`:

```
mUEHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            try {

                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        openFileOutput(DMP_FILENAME, 0)));
                e.printStackTrace(pw);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // do nothing
            }
            BaseActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUEHandler);
```

This writes every unhandled exception in your app that happened on your activity to text file. Then you can analyze it.

Comment: @Thanks for your valuable replay.

Comment: You are welcome. Hope this is what you want to support your testers.

Comment: This is great and I know it has been a while, but is there a way for it still to display the "Unfortunately, App has stopped"?

Comment: Hey @jhnewkirk, hope this is not too late to answer your question. What you'll have to do to let the app fail as usual, is to re-throw the exception. Check out the throw keyword for java. Note the "uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)". throw that "Throwable e" that the method supplies back to you.

Comment: Update to my previous comment. My bad, it seems that you can't rethrow the Exception because you'll have to try/catch a throw.

Answer (score 2):

I use ACRA http://code.google.com/p/acra/ to collect crash reports. Since these are collected into Google docs-based spreadsheet you can configure to be notified when that doc is updated

Comment: I found ACRA was useful at first, but the Google Doc it posted to rapidly became overwhelmed with the details.  It needs very frequent 'clean up'.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your application to the Android Market, then Google sends crash reports to your e-mail too. Actually Google sends unhandled exceptions that occur in application that leads to crash (force close). No special code is needed for that.

Comment: @Thanks for answer,i need check my app in  testing level,so i need crash report..

Comment: @because my app is testing by 100 members,so i find crash report in testing level